# Listen for updates ans install from server

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, updates

1. First I have a server.I check server is there any `new apk` file I download this and try to install.
2. If server have `new version of apk file` then I want to **update my .apk file**.
3. I want to **Install/update without user interaction**.Is it possible?
4. If user interaction is needed then How can I install/update .apk file.

I don't have idea much more about that.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "jarviz.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But this is not working.WHen I debugging I can not see any mistake but it does not install.How can I do that.Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Play Store to distribute your app? It will take care of all of this for you. As far as I know, there is no way to install apps without user interaction, and I don't think you can do it programmatically. Either would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Fair warning: By not using Google Play and putting your apk out there for the public it is possible for someone to take your apk, unzip it and redistribute as their own, if they wanted to.

Comment: @Asok you say that having it on Google Play makes any difference in that subject? :)

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com :) Very good point, I guess if one had the know how and drive then any location has direct apk accessibility, [cough, cough](http://www.computric.com/2012/04/how-to-download-apk-files-from-google-play-to-pc/). _Paranoia settling in.._

Comment: If there's a need, there's a way. Or rooted device :)

Comment: @Tanis.7x @-Asok @ WebnetMobile.com Thnks .But I agree with you If there need user interaction then I have no issue. secondly My idea is I upload my apk file int my own server .from the device's I  want to check there is any new .apk file or update version is available.then I download and install . Is there need rooted I have no issue .I show a notifiaction to user plz rooted device.So plz let me know.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com  
If there's a need, there's a way. Or rooted device :) How IS THIS POSSIBLE ?How can rooted my device from code? or Should I notify to user that plz root ur system.Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue this way.

```
String vsName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/";
File file = new File(vsName, "jarviz.apk");
System.out.println(":"+file);
Intent install=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(install);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct but you just created the intent. You yet need to fire it to make any effect:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

and make sure you download your `jarviz.apk` indeed to `download/` folder on external storage as you refer to it in the intent.

Comment: @ WebnetMobile.com I already check .I got below this error.                                        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }                 Let me know.